# Am I commiting an act of shirk

Tags: shirk, masjid

Am I commiting Shirk if I go to the masjid just to see my friends and talk to them.  But my prayers are for Allah

Answer (score -1):

This is not shirk. Going to the masjid to see friends is very good but you must also have the intention of pleasing Allah and going to the masjid for his sake but wanting to see friends there also is good too and you will be rewarded by Allah for brotherhood with other Muslims. If someone goes to the masjid to show off and purposely try to impress others with his piety then that is what is called ‘Riyah’ which is a form of shirk and making partners with Allah but it is minor shirk not major shirk. Major shirk is kufr that takes a person out of Islam and will never be forgiven by Allah if a person dies upon it without having repented for it and they will be punished in hellfire permanently. Minor shirk on the other hand is a major sin but it is not kufr and does not take one out of Islam and if a person dies upon it without having repented, he won’t be in hellfire forever if he ends up going to hellfire for some time and will eventually be forgiven and let into Heaven